# VBA Excel - Select a value from one cell in Excel to update a SQL table

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am working on a project to track profit and loss from a billing standpoint. We have a per piece cost that I am using to track the expenses. The end user would like to be able to change the per piece cost from time to time prior to update the table. I am trying to us a macro to take a value from sheet3 cell B2 in the Excel worksheet in order to update a table in SQL server. I am missing something as when I run the macro it does not update the table. Could anyone tell me what I am missing. This is my first attempt at using VBA so I'm stuck for the moment.

```
Sub UpdateSQLData()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection

Dim MySQL As String

Worksheets("Sheet3").Visible = True
Worksheets("Sheet3").Select

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection



cnn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial Catalog=database;Data Source=server;UID=uid;PWD=pwd;"


Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
For i = 2 To Range("B2").Select
MySQL = "UPDATE opi_bill_cost " & _
"SET Cost ='" & Range("B2").Value & "', Outcome = '"


cnn.Execute MySQL
Next i

cnn.Close

Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Your SQL is never executed because Range("B2").Select returns True which VBA will interpret as -1.

Comment: Your SQL has quotes around what seems to be a numeric value, and did you remove something from the end of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only running one update statement, you don't need a For Loop, which you would only use if you wanted to run multiple update statements with different values.

You For Loop is also the cause of nothing running. A for loop needs to run between 2 values, whereas Range("B2").Select is an action. It's actually trying to run from "2" to "TRUE" (after successfully selecting a range), which is never true. So it skips over the lines of code for updating.

Try taking out the For... line and the Next line. That might be enough to make it work. At the very least, the code will run and throw an error if there are any other issues.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be working now. Now to figure out how to automatically run the macro when the value in the cell changes. It seems like it is straight forward but again not actually working.

Comment: That's a whole other question. To find out how to run code automatically, google for: excel worksheet change event. However that's risky because users may accidentally enter a wrong value they don't want updated. It would be safer to add a command button or shape directly to the sheet and assign the macro to it. Since this answer solves your question here, please mark this as your accepted answer. Thanks.